# Android Espresso - Testing a ListView row

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, android-espresso

I'm currently trying to test a `ListView` on android with Espresso, with a custom `ArrayAdapter`. 
Here is the test :

```
 final AssociationsListActivity listActivity = getActivity();

    final Association association1 = new Association(ASSOCIATION_NAMES[0], ASSOCIATION_DESCRIPTIONS[0]);
    final Association association2 = new Association(ASSOCIATION_NAMES[1], ASSOCIATION_DESCRIPTIONS[1]);
    final Association association3 = new Association(ASSOCIATION_NAMES[2], ASSOCIATION_DESCRIPTIONS[2]);

    listActivity.addAssociation(association1);
    listActivity.addAssociation(association2);
    listActivity.addAssociation(association3);

    assertTrue(listActivity.getAssociationsList().size() == 3);

    onView(withId(R.id.associationsListView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onData(anything())
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.associationsListView))
            .atPosition(0)
            .perform(click());

    assertCurrentActivityIsInstanceOf(AssociationsListActivityTest.this
            , AssociationsPageActivity.class);
```

The method `listActivity.addAssociation(association);` simply does `associationArrayAdapter.add(association);`.

The `ArrayAdapter`is used to add elements to a `ListView`(visible by default) with the id `R.id.associationsListView`

When I run this test, I get the following error :

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
Got: "ListView{id=2131427414, res-name=associationsListView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=996, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=42.0, child-count=0}"
```

Which is caused by the following assertion, `onView(withId(R.id.associationsListView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

Also when commenting this assertion, the next one causes the following exception :

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: ch.epfl.sweng.project:id/associationsListView'.
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView and is displayed on the screen to the user)
Target view: "ListView{id=2131427414, res-name=associationsListView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=996, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=42.0, child-count=0}"
```

I went through a lot of stack overflow threads covering those exception, I replaced those tests by other equivalents but those errors still show up I don't know what to do! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong!

My method to add elements to the `ArrayAdapter` used `runOnUIThread` but it seems that the test was not waiting for this method, thus the `associationsListView`was considered as not displayed to the user ! So I fixed my method `listActivity.addAssociation(Association association)` like this :

```
public void addAssociation(final Association association) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!associationList.contains(association)) {
                associationArrayAdapter.add(association);
            }
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!associationList.contains(association)) {
        associationList.add(association);
    }
}
```

All parts of the test now pass :)